# Validate number and then format to decimal

Tags: bash, awk, decimal

Post Edited:

I have a function in my script that doesn't work like I want.
The goal is to validate numbers and then formatting into decimal.

So I created a test-file thats looks like my function ...

```
TMP_NUM="$1"
if [[ "$TMP_NUM" = *[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
    if [[ "$TMP_NUM" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] ; then
        echo "$TMP_NUM"
    else
        TMP_DECIMAL=$(awk -v decimal="$TMP_NUM" 'BEGIN {printf("%f", decimal) }')
        if [[ "$TMP_DECIMAL" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] ; then
            echo "$TMP_DECIMAL"
        else
            echo "failed !"
        fi
    fi
else
    echo "failed !"
fi
exit 0
```

the results ...

```
mario@antec:~$ test.function4.sh 1e-06
0.000001
mario@antec:~$ test.function4.sh 1e-05
0.000010
mario@antec:~$ test.function4.sh 0Hallo
0.000000
```

How do I have to change the test parameters to get only numbers formatted, and an error message when any letters are behind any numbers, except eE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

define this function

```
test_number() { awk -v v="$1" 'BEGIN{if(v+0==v) printf "%f\n",v; else print "failed!"}';}
```

usage

```
$ test_number XXX
failed!
$ test_number 2323
2323.000000
$ test_number 0.23234
0.232340
$ test_number 0.23234XX
failed!
$ test_number 0.23234E4
2323.400000
```

Comment: Probably use a different name for the function?  `test` can interfere with the shell builtin.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code this way - check the number before formatting it:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP_NUM="$1"
if [[ "$TMP_NUM" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
  TMP_DECIMAL=$(awk -v decimal="$TMP_NUM" 'BEGIN {printf("%f", decimal) }')
  echo "$TMP_DECIMAL"
else
  echo "failed !"
fi
```

`printf` is rounding your number.  You can change your format string to specify how many decimals you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to format my string to specify digits after the point ?  Unfortunately I misswrote my script and had to edit my post.